# StorIO observeChangesInTable, can i get updated rows/items with it?

Tags: storio

StorIOSQLite has interesting method observeChangesInTable(). And When I saw it I thought that it would observe changes in given table and return list of updated items.

But it just returns updated table name. Why would I need an updated table name? I can just subscribe to hole table to be notified about an update

```
storIoSqLite.get()
            .listOfObjects(Item.class)
            .withQuery(
                    Query.builder()
                            .table(ItemTable.NAME)
                            .build()
            )
            .prepare()
            .asRxObservable()
```

Please explain what is the point of observeChangesInTable() method. And what is the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your approach you're actually doing a `query` to the db and only **then** reacting to the change.

With `StorIOSQLite.observeChangesInTable()` you can react on changes in the table **without** doing any `queries` to the db. This is much much cheaper and should be used in situations when you need to do a `debounce()` or `window()`, `filter()` etc and only then make actual `query` to the db.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Do you think it's worth to open a feature request for List<Items> observeChangesInTable() method. Is it archivable with storIo? I believe this is a common need.

Comment: What do you mean by `List<Items> observeChangesInTable()`?

Comment: StorIO has `Get` operation for that which reacts on changes in db and emits query result (one of the variants is `get().listOfObjects(Some.class)`

Comment: Yeah, but it always returns result for the same query. In my case there's a chat and I need to display new messages, passing each time new updatedAt argument, therefore updating the query.

Comment: Then I'd suggest to `observeChangesInTable().flatMap(change -> get().something()`)